Segmentation Fault When Importing osqp in Python on MacOS
I'm experiencing a segmentation fault when trying to import the osqp package in Python on my MacOS system. I've tried to isolate the environment by using a virtual environment. Here are my System Specs:
System Information:
MacOS Version: macOS Big Sur 11.7.10
Python Version: Python 3.11.2
Additional Information:

I have tried reinstalling Python and creating the virtual environment multiple times.
Other packages install and import without issues.
I have also tried installing osqp with different versions but the problem persists.

Steps to Reproduce:

Create a new virtual environment.
Upgrade pip to the latest version.
Install the osqp package.
Attempt to import the osqp package using the verbose setting.

Detailed Steps:
Here is what I input in the terminal and I have included the last logs for step 3 and 5 showing that installation is successful but import fails with a segmentation fault.
# Step 1: Create a new virtual environment
python3.11 -m venv venv

# Step 2: Activate the virtual environment
source venv/bin/activate

# Step 3: Upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade pip

# Step 4: Install osqp
pip install osqp

**Installing collected packages: numpy, scipy, qdldl, osqp
Successfully installed numpy-2.0.0 osqp-0.6.7.post0 qdldl-0.1.7.post4 scipy-1.14.0**

# Step 5: Try to import osqp
python -v -c "import osqp"

**import 'osqp.utils' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x113323650>
zsh: segmentation fault  python -v -c "import osqp"**


Getting Segmentation Fault
Instead of importing normally, it results in a segmentation fault and crashes the python session.

Try installing NumPy 1.x first, then install osqp. Possibly, NumPy 2.x is incompatible with osqp.
